# List index out of range, but cannot find what is making it out of range

Tags: python, arrays

My Python code is throwing an exception here on this line, giving a "list index out of range" error, but I cannot find which part of my code is making i or r out of the array's range.

```
import time
import random
import math

sudoLine = [0,0,0]
possibleNums = [1,2,3]

print(len(possibleNums))

length = len(possibleNums) - 1
for i in range(3):
    r = random.randint(0,length)
    sudoLine[i] = possibleNums[r]
    possibleNums.pop(r)

print(sudoLine)
```

The error message is as follows:

```
  Message=list index out of range
  Source=C:\Users\heyma\source\repos\Sudoku Solver\Sudoku Solver\Sudoku_Solver.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\heyma\source\repos\Sudoku Solver\Sudoku Solver\Sudoku_Solver.py", line 18, in <module> (Current frame)
    sudoLine[i] = possibleNums[r]
```

Sorry if this is a bad question, I'm fairly new as this is my first project!

Comment: Did you try any debugging? Running it through e.g. https://pythontutor.com/ should make it obvious which part is out of range (you may need to run it a few times, due to the random nature of the implementation). But it seems like you want `sudoLine` to be `possibleNums` in a random order, there are easier ways to do that.

Comment: You change the size of `possibleNums` when calling `pop` but never update `length` with the new value

Comment: It seems that adding `random.seed(1)` gets it to crash reproducibly on PythonTutor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the length of `possibleNums` is decreasing with every iteration of the for-loop but you only calculate the `length` variable once (before the loop). Move the line `length = len(possibleNums) - 1` inside the for-loop:

```
import time
import random
import math

sudoLine = [0,0,0]
possibleNums = [1,2,3]

print(len(possibleNums))


for i in range(3):
    length = len(possibleNums) - 1
    r = random.randint(0,length)
    sudoLine[i] = possibleNums[r]
    possibleNums.pop(r)

print(sudoLine)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `pop` method removes an element from a list. So your `possibleNums` list is getting shorter with each iteration.

So at some point the value of `r` might be chosen to be greater that the current length of `possibleNums`.

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown because the length of the `possibleNums` list changed after `pop` command was issued. Therefore reducing the number of indexes.

```py
import random

sudoLine = [0,0,0]
possible_nums = [1,2,3]
i = 0

while len(possible_nums) > 0:
  length = len(possible_nums) - 1
  r = random.randint(0, length)
  sudoLine[i] = possible_nums[r]
  possible_nums.pop(r)
  i += 1


print(sudoLine)
```

Comment: This still has the same issue, `possible_nums` gets shorter with each iteration

Comment: Thanks for sharing feedback  @Arseny and @DeepSpace! I've fixed the code so it can work